# How to run homogeneity chi-square test with Fisher's exact test in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a table

```
smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
smoke <- as.table(smoke)
```

I know that I can run homogeneity test by running:

```
chisq.test (smoke, correct = FALSE)
```

But it will run Pearson's chi square test. How can I run the homogeneity test with Fisher's exact test?

Comment: Is `fisher.test` what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, I know fisher.test, but I think fisher.test will run two - way test. Is there a way to run fisher.test for homogeneity?